# Rewrite edited XLSX file in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

In this page I found some code exaples and after sticking it together I'm trying to make it work. Page can read uploaded XLSX file ant print every cell in forms text field. But I cant find out, how to add edited information into the same cells where it was before?
Please help!

```
<?php
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("Ataskaita3.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
echo '<form name="forma" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'">';
echo '<table border=1>' . "\n";
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
  echo '<tr>' . "\n";
  $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
  $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); 
  foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="laukelis" value="' . $cell->getValue() . '"/></td>' . "\n";
  }
  echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Redaguoti" />';
echo '</form>';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2 = $excel2->load('Ataskaita3.xlsx');
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', '4')
    ->setCellValue('A2', '5')
    ->setCellValue('A3', '6')       
    ->setCellValue('A4', '7');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('Ataskaita_redaguota.xlsx');
}else{
echo 'edit';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd start by ensuring that every cell (input field) in your form has a different name

Comment: so I have to make it as array laukelis[] or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with:

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="' . $cell->getCoordinate() . '" value="' . $cell->getValue() . '"/></td>' . "\n";
```

Comment: I'm new in PHPExcel so how to put all form values to opened document? ->setCellValue..?

Comment: When the form is submitted, loop through all the cells and test the form field that matches the $cell->getCoordinate() value... that's the value to store in that cell

Comment: how to get the cell coordinate printed? If I echo $_POST[$cell->getCoordinate()]; I get field value, but how to print that field name? foreach ($_POST[$cell->getCoordinate()] as $key => $value){ ?

Comment: yea, I find out that. echo '' . $cell->getCoordinate() . '' . $cell->getValue() . ''; But how to get through loop, to print all form values, with foreach i'm getting error

Comment: `foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
print "$name : $value<br>";
$excel2->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('$name', '$value');
}` I found this working ir prints all values, but when trying to insert into document getting this: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Cell coordinate must not be absolute.' ...

Comment: So check exactly what is in $name

Comment: I noticed, that in all these data also there is included submit button value. Somehow i need to skip it.